# Did any actor ever win an Oscar for their work in a horror movie?

Tags: horror, academy-awards

I was wondering how it is possible that Jack Nicholson wasn't nominated for his acting in *The Shining*.

Did any actor ever win an Oscar for their work in a horror movie?

Comment: And to be fair to the Academy, the Best Actor nominations list for 1981 is fairly credible! You could put Nicholson in it, you could not put him in it...

Comment: Yes, is credible, in fact in my question i wrote that it was an opinion-based thought, but who edited my question deleted that part eheh

Answer (score 75):

Of course they did:

- *Rosemary's Baby*: [Ruth Gordon won for Best Supporting Actress](http://www.moviesonline.ca/14-oscar-winning-horror-movies/)
- *Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde* (1931): ["Fredric March’s performance as the title character(s) earned the film a Best Leading Actor statue"](http://www.dreadcentral.com/top-10-lists/90450/10-horror-movies-actually-won-academy-awards/)
- *Silence of the Lambs*: ["one of only three films to win all of the “Big Five” awards, which also include Best Director, Best Actor, Best Actress and Best Screenplay."](http://www.dreadcentral.com/top-10-lists/90450/10-horror-movies-actually-won-academy-awards/3/)
- *Black Swan*: ["Natalie Portman was presented with the naked gold dude for her performance as a mad ballet dancer in the dark re-telling of Swan Lake"](http://www.dreadcentral.com/top-10-lists/90450/10-horror-movies-actually-won-academy-awards/3/)
- *Misery*: ["Best Actress: Kathy Bates"](http://horror.about.com/od/horrorthemelists/ss/horroroscars.htm#step7)

Comment: Seems debateable whether some of these are horror films. (But on the other hand, what constitutes *any* particular genre? Lines are blurry.)

Comment: I consider Silence of the Lambs, Misery and Black Sawn as a Thriller, but great answer anyway ;)

Comment: I usually defer to IMDb for genres, since although it may not be a perfect classification, it's at least well-known and generally accepted one. *Rosemary's Baby* is Drama/ **Horror**, *Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde* (1931) is **Horror** /Sci-fi, *Silence of the Lambs* is Crime/Drama/Thriller, *Black Swan* is Drama/Thriller, and *Misery* is Crime/Drama/Thriller. So according to IMDb, only the first two movies on the list count.

Comment: Black Swan is nowhere near being a horror movie. Some psycho elements - yes.

Comment: ["Q: Is Black Swan a horror movie? A: Not in the traditional sense. I mean, it’s not a gory *Saw-*type movie. But, for lack of a better term, Black Swan is one dark, f***ed-up movie."](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2010/12/is-black-swan-a-horror-movie-and-24-other-urgent-questions) Also: ["Black Swan's Greatest Trick Was Convincing Oscar That It Isn't Horror"](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Black-Swan-Greatest-Trick-Was-Convincing-Oscar-It-Isn-t-Horror-23334.html)

Comment: Just my personal opinion, but I generally consider "Thriller" to be a form of "Horror."  (ie: suspense-horror vs gore-horror.)  There are certainly some movies officially labeled "Thriller" that might be better described as "Action/Adventure" but I usually consider that a failing of whoever categorized the movie rather than a failing of what "Thriller" means.  In particular (and again, just IMHO) all of the movies above can properly be called horror, even if they aren't officially labeled "Horror."

Comment: Since we're on a Q&A site about movies, [I've asked a question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/67566/12783) about the difference between the horror genre and the thriller genre.

Comment: @Steve-O Hitchcock's *Rear Window* and *Vertigo* are, I think, both considered "thrillers"--to me they almost seem to epitomize the genre. But I really don't see them as "horror" movies at all; do you?

Comment: _Silence_ is a horror film if you consider that the A-plot is Clarice's troublingly intimate relationship with the absolutely singular monster Dr Hannibal Lecter. First-time viewers spend a lot of the movie wondering if she will fail to adequately protect her mind from an insatiable predator who can convince a fellow inmate to suicide by swallowing his own tongue. The hunt for Buffalo Bill is just an excuse to bring them together.

Answer (score 22):

Ruth Gordon [won](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063522/awards) Best Supporting Actress in *Rosemary's Baby*.

[This](http://www.moviesonline.ca/14-oscar-winning-horror-movies/) article lists 14 horror films "noticed" by the Academy, including *Misery* and *Silence of the Lambs*. Whether these two can be classified as horrors is arguable, but if so, you can also add Kathy Bates, Jodie Foster and Anthony Hopkins to the list.